# Ctrl + L doesn't work on embedded system

Tags: bash, embedded-linux

I am working on an embedded system (consider a layer 2 switch running linux). I am connected to it using putty ssh.

When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd>, it doesn't clear the screen. While the same thing works on Ubuntu machine.

I want to understand why the key combination is working on normal linux machine, not on switch.

Comment: Terminal settings perhaps on the switch is not VT220/VT100 compatible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> combination is handled by the terminal, not the shell. Unless you configure PuTTY to acknowledge it (assuming you even can in the first place), it will have no effect.